# Use sed to duplicate a line in an xml and keep the same indentation

Tags: xml, regex, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to add a new tag to a large number of xml files in bulk.

A sample xml is as follows:

```
<attribute name="MyAttribute">
    <type>
        <long>
            <range>
                <min>0</min>
                <max>100000</max>
            </range>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
        </long>
    </type>
</attribute>
```

In the sample above, I have a "type" tag with a certain indentation. I want to be able to do the following:

1. Find all of the instances of this "type" tag
2. Copy the line where the tag exists, including the indentation (The
   indentation is not consistent throughout the files so cannot be a
   hardcoded value)
3. Paste in a new tag, for example "myAddedTag", just above the "type"
   tag and maintain the indentation

Expected result:

```
<attribute name="MyAttribute">
    <myAddedTag>
    <type>
        <long>
            <range>
                <min>0</min>
                <max>100000</max>
            </range>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
        </long>
    </type>
</attribute>
```

I have been using sed to find and replace the type tag in a shell script with something like the command below, but my problem is the indentation - I can't seem to figure out how to maintain it. I have tried adding spaces, but the indentation is not the same in all files.

Sample sed command is as follows:
File: my_sample_sed_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -i "s/<type>/<myAddedTag \/>\n<type>/g"  $1
```

And I call the script using this command in bash:

```
my_sed_script.sh sample.xml
```

However, the output is as follows - see the type tag has no indentation:

```
<attribute name="MyAttribute">
        <myAddedTag>
<type>
            <long>
                <range>
                    <min>0</min>
                    <max>100000</max>
                </range>
                <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
            </long>
        </type>
    </attribute>
```

Any help would be appreciated. As I mentioned, my problem is trying to find a solution to getting the indentation to be the same as the line I am copying/replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/^\(\s\+\)<type>/\1<myAddedTag \/>\n&/g' yourfile
```

Comment: This appears to work quite well for what I want - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sed` to work on XML.

Use an XML-aware tool like `xsltproc` and this XSLT stylesheet:

```
<!-- add_attribute.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- copy everything ... -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  <attribute name="MyAttribute"> special case -->
    <xsl:template match="attribute[@name='MyAttribute']">
        <!-- copy element and its attributes -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

            <!-- copy first, whitespace-only text node (i.e. the indentation) -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="text()[1][normalize-space() = '']" />

            <!-- add your tag -->
            <myAddedTag />

            <!-- copy rest of the contents -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Usage:

```
xsltproc add_attribute.xsl your_file.xml
```

Output:

```
<attribute name="MyAttribute">
    <myAddedTag/>
    <type>
        <long>
            <range>
                <min>0</min>
                <max>100000</max>
            </range>
            <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
        </long>
    </type>
</attribute>
```

The benefit is that the chances of structurally breaking the XML are zero while you can do complex modifications in a fundamentally more maintainable and flexible way than with regular expressions.

Comment: That's brilliant, I wasn't aware of this functionality. I have multiple xmls, with a large number of different attribute names and some attributes have more than the specified tags. Have you any suggestions as to how I could implement this solution across different attribute names?

Comment: Well you can easily extend the XSLT stylesheet. Just add an  `<xsl:template>` for every special case you have to handle. Copy the template I made, adapt the match expression, change the contents. You can have as many templates as you like in the same XSLT file, one for every case in your input, easily covering all your different requirements.

Comment: The only part of that xslt which is specific to that change is the `match` statement and the added tag itself. The rest is just "framework". You can change either of those to anything you want. You can even have multiple different `<xsl:template>` stanzas in the same xslt which do different things to different input elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - I will give this ago as it is obviously the more robust solution. Thanks!

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask specific questions as you stuble upon them. XSLT has a learning curve because it's quite different from "usual" programming languages. If you work on XML often, then in the end it will be worth the effort. Just like learning regex is worth the effort if you work on text a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you are willing to use perl or python forr your task.

```
(.+?)(?=(\s*)<type>)(.*)$
```

Try this.This retains indentation.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/2

Comment: This will only add one tag to the file, the OPs version supports multiple tags. I don't know if that's a requirement or not.

Comment: @EtanReisner that can be included too using lookaheads.But OP wants in sed.So this just might give a hint or too .

Comment: Doesn't HAVE to be sed - I just figured this was the best way to go about it. I can use anything provided it can be automated to run on multiple xml files. I also need to add this to multiple tags within one file

Comment: Also, I am trying this command out now (thanks by the way), but I am getting an error - can you point me in the right direction?
New script:
sed 's/(.+?)(?=(\s*)<type>)(.*)$/$1\2<myaddedtag>$3/g' sample.xml

I get this error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 48: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS @EtanReisner

Comment: What is the error and how are you implementing this

Comment: This has to be used with python and Perl not sed as I mentioned in my ans